# R: how to display the first n characters from a string of words

Tags: r, string, substr, strsplit

I have the following string:

```
 Getty <- "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all  men are created equal."
```

I want to display the first 10 characters. So I began by splitting the string into individual characters:

```
 split <- strsplit(Getty, split="")
 split
```

I get all the individual characters as this point. Then I make a substring of the first 10 characters.

```
 first.10 <- substr(split, start=1, stop=10)
 first.10
```

And here is the output:

```
 "c(\"F\", \"o\""
```

I am not understanding why this prints out? I thought it would just print out something like:

```
 "F" "o" "u" "r" "s"
```

Is there a way I can alter my code to print what I have above?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: just use `split[[1]][1:10]`, you don't need `substr`.

Comment: why not using directly `substr(Getty,1,10)` ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel  I guess the OP wanted to extract each character

Comment: You could also do `substring(gsub("\\s+", "", Getty), 1:10, 1:10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers didn't eliminate the spaces as you did in your example, so I'll add this:

```
strsplit(substr(gsub("\\s+", "", Getty), 1, 10), '')[[1]]
#[1] "F" "o" "u" "r" "s" "c" "o" "r" "e" "a"
```

Answer (score 5):

Turn your code around and you get what you want.

```
Getty <- "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all  men are created equal."


first.10 <- substr(Getty, start=1, stop=10)
first.10
"Four score"
split <- strsplit(first.10, split="")
split 
"F" "o" "u" "r" " " "s" "c" "o" "r" "e"
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you got  `"c(\"F\", \"o\""` is because the `strsplit` output is a `list`.  We can convert the `list` to `vector` by extracting the first `list` element ie. `[[1]]`.  Use the `head` to get the first 10 characters.

```
head(strsplit(Getty, '')[[1]], 10)
```

#### Update

If you just want to extract characters without the spaces,

```
library(stringr)
head(str_extract_all(Getty, '[^ ]')[[1]],10)
#[1] "F" "o" "u" "r" "s" "c" "o" "r" "e" "a"
```